# How to group array of objects by common property and put other properties together

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, reduce

I have an array of objects like this

```
const statuses = [
  {time: '21/1/1990', 'Status.sold': 8848},
  {time: '21/1/1990', 'Status.reserved': 8804},
  {time: '21/1/1991', 'Status.reserved': 8756},
  {time: '21/1/1991', 'Status.sold': 8732},
  {time: '21/1/1992', 'Status.killed': 8691},
  {time: '21/1/1992', 'Status.sold': 8620},
  {time: '21/1/1993', 'Status.held': 8511},
  {time: '21/1/1993', 'Status.killed': 8511},
  {time: '21/1/1994', 'Status.sold': 8498},
];
```

and what I am trying to achieve is to put all `Status.` properties together and grouped by the `time` property, which is common for all objects. So the final result will be like this

```
const statuses = [
  {time: '21/1/1990', sold: 8848, killed: 0, reserved: 8804, held: 0},
  {time: '21/1/1991', sold: 8732, killed: 0, reserved: 8756, held: 0},
  {time: '21/1/1992', sold: 8620, killed: 8691, reserved: 0, held: 0},
  {time: '21/1/1993', sold: 0, killed: 8511, reserved: 0, held: 8511},
  {time: '21/1/1994', sold: 8498, killed: 0, reserved: 0, held: 0},
];
```

I have tried something like this

```
const result = statuses.map((obj) => {
   return { ...obj, 
      sold: obj['Status.sold'] ? obj['Status.sold'] : 0,
      reserved: obj['Status.reserved'] ? obj['Status.reserved'] : 0,
      killed: obj['Status.killed'] ? obj['Status.killed'] : 0,
      held: obj['Status.held'] ? obj['Status.held'] : 0
   };
});
```

but I'm not sure how to group them by `time`. How can I combine reduce method with this code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `reduce` function

Comment: Take a look here: [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object for grouping by `time`.

```js
const
    statuses = [{ time: '21/1/1990', 'Status.sold': 8848 }, { time: '21/1/1990', 'Status.reserved': 8804 }, { time: '21/1/1991', 'Status.reserved': 8756 }, { time: '21/1/1991', 'Status.sold': 8732 }, { time: '21/1/1992', 'Status.killed': 8691 }, { time: '21/1/1992', 'Status.sold': 8620 }, { time: '21/1/1993', 'Status.held': 8511 }, { time: '21/1/1993', 'Status.killed': 8511 }, { time: '21/1/1994', 'Status.sold': 8498 }],
    result = Object.values(statuses.reduce((r, { time, ...o }) => {
        r[time] ??= { time, sold: 0, killed: 0, reserved: 0, held: 0 };
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => r[time][k.slice(7)] += v);
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Can you please explain to me why do we need `k.slice(7)` ? Thanks!

Comment: this is to get only the word `'killed'` from `'Status.sold'`, for example. maybe you wante the complete string or a nested approach by using the splitted values ...?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const statuses = [
  {time: '21/1/1990', 'Status.sold': 8848},
  {time: '21/1/1990', 'Status.reserved': 8804},
  {time: '21/1/1991', 'Status.reserved': 8756},
  {time: '21/1/1991', 'Status.sold': 8732},
  {time: '21/1/1992', 'Status.killed': 8691},
  {time: '21/1/1992', 'Status.sold': 8620},
  {time: '21/1/1993', 'Status.held': 8511},
  {time: '21/1/1993', 'Status.killed': 8511},
  {time: '21/1/1994', 'Status.sold': 8498},
];

const result = [];

let obj = {};
for (let i = 0; i < statuses.length; i++) {
  const status = statuses[i];
  if (status.time != obj.time) {
    if (i != 0) result.push(obj); 
    obj = {
      time: status.time,
      sold: 0,
      reserved: 0,
      killed: 0,
      held: 0,
    }
  }
  if (status['Status.sold']) obj.sold += status['Status.sold'];
  if (status['Status.reserved']) obj.reserved += status['Status.reserved'];
  if (status['Status.killed']) obj.killed += status['Status.killed'];
  if (status['Status.held']) obj.held += status['Status.held'];
}
result.push(obj);
console.log(result);
```